# Creating TextView with given style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview

I am working on action bar of an android application. I want an action Item with `actionLayout` as

[image]

I have read somewhere the easiest way to do is to have `TextView` with the specific style.
I know how to integrate the `TextView` with the `actionLayout` attribute of `item` in `menu` xml file.

The only thing I am looking for is that specific style. I have tried a lot of `android:style` . None helps

THE BOTTOM SHADOW APPEARING ON THE IMAGE IS NOT THE PART OF THE ACTION BUTTON

Comment: Please use custom layout for it and search for custom layout in actionLayout

Comment: How to create that custom layout

Comment: search on google you will find code for it

Comment: What should I search for ... I mean what would you call this text view

Comment: `custom layout in menu actionbar android ` search with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your XML file:

`<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/yourimage"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />`

do this in your code n use 9.pach drawable file

Comment: what is 9 pach drawable file

Comment: that's make your image starch-able search on google how to make 9pach file